# Mongo db selection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection like the following

```
array(

'Pinned' => 
  array (
    '0' => 
    array (
      'PageId' => '511b6b482284a5481d000000',
      'PageTitle' => 'VOIP Business',
    ),
    '1' => 
    array (
      'PageId' => '511b6b482284a5481d000001',
      'PageTitle' => 'Dialers',
    ),
  ),
  'ReportAbuse' => 0,

)
```

"Pinned" can contain multiple arrays inside it. I need find those documents that have

```
'PageId' => '511b6b482284a5481d000000'
```

inside Pinned.

So i tried

```
'Pinned' => array(
      'PageId' => '511b6b482284a5481d000000'
)
```

But i didn't work. 
I hope my question is clear :). Please help me if any one knows the answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need your language's equivalent of :

```
find({'Pinned.PageId': '511b6b482284a5481d000000'})
```

Note that this only works for the top level array.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It seems that Pinned.0.PageId seems to work. but the problem is i wont know the index (0). So is there a way inside mongo to iterate my Pinned array and search for the match.

Comment: No, if .0. works it means you're working with nested arrays which is not supported for queries. It's usually also a schema smell so refactoring your schema might be the right way forward.

Answer (score 0):

Querying and manipulating array elements are currently only supported for top-level arrays, not for nested arrays - see the $ position operator in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/

This may change in the future, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

In the meanwhile querying and updating of nested arrays have to be done on the client side:

- read the document into a variable
- manipulate the array
- update the document, rewriting the entire array